# How to deregister firebase push registration token?

Tags: http, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am a backend web developer. I am trying to use firebase for push notifications but I began to wonder if the app client deactivates his account, then I could just delete the client's registration token, but is it also possible to request FCM to delete the client's push token that I saved in database?